# DFA without final state

Tags: regular-language, dfa, state-machine

We can have a `Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA)` without final state. Whether it's meant!
What is the meaning of a `Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA)` without final state?

Thanks

Comment: Note that there is a difference between "finite" and "final". Finite means a finite number of states. Why should that be a problem? Certainly an automata _does_ have a finite number of states. Everything else would be _very_ surprising.

Comment: Ok! Question edited. Thanks

Comment: Still not a question that makes sense. Why should a DFA require a final state? Who says so? It can go on in circles, where is the problem? Actually most DFAs do...

Comment: @arkascha transducer can be without any final state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Possible. If an automata is not acceptor but transducer then final state is not needed.

Any class of an automata can be without a final state! An automata can be thought as a finite representation of a formal language(that can be infinite set). An automata with the final state(s) is called **acceptor**. For example, A DFA as acceptor either accepts or reject a string and represents a regular language.

But another model of automata is called [transducer](http://www.eti.pg.gda.pl/katedry/kiw/pracownicy/Jan.Daciuk/personal/thesis/node13.html) that may not have any final state. The purpose of automata as a transducer is to produce output string for a given input string.
Example for [finite state machine as transducer](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Seq/fsm.html) is Mealy and Moor machine.